# Issues with converting HTML file to master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

Right now I have an HTML file and I'm trying to convert it to a master page. I'm using a VM on CloudShare.

So I create a new site collection and go into the site settings. Under “Look and Feel”, Design Manager isn’t there so I’ve found that if I go to “Site Collection Features” under “Site Collection Administration”, and activate “SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” Design Manager will show up. So I go into design manager, but under Edit Master Pages none of the file or folder names will show up, and when I convert the html file the status column doesn’t show up either, so I can’t go to preview it or to the snippets gallery.

The only thing I can find online is to create a new site collection, which I’ve tried a few times. This happened on my old CloudShare VM, and creating a new site collection fixed it, but it’s not working for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Figured it out - I made a new site collection and set it to a Publishing site template and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I made a new site collection and set it to a Publishing site template and it fixed the issue